# Jquery datatable having column with text fields.Add search mechanism to this

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery Datatable plugin.

Datatable having column with text fields.

My column contains {G 110cc, G 234cc,T 123cc,T 543ff, G 344fg, F 454gg,...} these kind of entries.
I want to search series wise i.e. if i type G i want only G series entries to display or T for
T series and so on..

Also i want to display column sorted(have input text field).

Please help.

Datatable version :1.9.4

Comment: You're not going to get a freply with a question like that. At the very least, provide a jsfiddle

Comment: Or at least tell us which version of Datatables you're using

Comment: ok, now tell us how you want to apply the search - a button external to the table?

Comment: Now I'm confused. Do you want to use the standard Datatable filter input to search a specific datatable column, or do you want to filter based on a value entered into a column field?

Comment: @markpsmith sorry for confusion,my mistake i didn't check actual issue

Comment: ok, i got this solution http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html 
but how to apply individual column filtering to column containing input text box